# Built dropdown with checkbox and input field, is it exists?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-components

I'm in a need of an existing component like ones that NGPrime is offering.

However it's a really special one.

It needs to be a dropdown with a checkbox or some other toggle functionality that toggles the built in input field's disabled state.

Like the combination of these ones, the checkbox should go in front of the filter field, and said field needs to be a regular input field so no built in fiter shinenigans.

[image]
[image]

I couldn't really seem to find something that fulfills my needs.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try mat-select from Angular Material. It can be combined with the mat-selection:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

You can add the search feature with ngx-mat-select-search.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search

PS: the images are not built in, but you can add them via CSS as ::before  to the mat-option.